# How can I represent ownership and lifetime of EGL types that will be stored in thread-local storage?

Tags: opengl, rust, ffi, egl

Here are the major EGL functions prototypes.

```
typedef void *EGLContext;

EGLContext eglCreateContext(EGLDisplay display,
    EGLConfig config,
    EGLContext share_context,
    EGLint const * attrib_list);

EGLBoolean eglMakeCurrent(EGLDisplay display,
    EGLSurface draw,
    EGLSurface read,
    EGLContext context);

EGLBoolean eglDestroyContext(EGLDisplay display,
    EGLContext context);
```

The instance of `EGLContext` returned from `eglCreateContext()` will be set to thread local storage by `eglMakeCurrent()`. After that, all the OpenGL or OpenGL ES functions will change the states held by that instance.

When I'm rewriting these EGL functions in Rust, how to properly deal with ownership and lifetimes?

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn eglCreateContext() -> EGLContext {
    // init instance of EGLContext
    // Rc::new(RefCell::new(instance of EGLContext));
    // return that instance of Rc?
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn eglMakeCurrent() -> EGLBoolean {
    // Clone a new Rc instance of the value returned by eglCreateContext?
    // How to set the new Rc instance to Thread Local Storage variable properly?
    // TLS can be None if eglMakeCurrent() pass a nullptr as actual value of EGLContext
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn eglDestroyContext(display: EGLDisplay, context: EGLContext) -> EGLBoolean {
    // Set TLS variable to None if context is already store in it
    // Dispose all the related resource.
}
```

Comment: *When I'm rewriting these EGL functions in Rust* — why would you **rewrite** these functions in Rust? Do you mean that you wish to **call** them?

Comment: No. I am not trying to call them through FFI. I am implementing them just like the normal graphics driver. I am writing an google/ANGLE alike project in Rust.